# Why is the adb command not listing my device?

Tags: android, macos, adb, osx-elcapitan

Lenovo A606
Android 4.4.2
OSX El Capitan
Developer mode is on
USB debugging is on
I already added the Android Tools Directory to PATH

When running `adb devices` on the command line, it just returns a blank list.

How can I make my laptop recognize my phone in order to test my code on a physical device?

Comment: Did you accepted the certificate in your device?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly your usb cord is just a charger?  When you plug in your phone can you see your pictures?  If not maybe try a different connector.

Comment: After change the conector (removing a hub mac) worked to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you find it out, let me know lol

There are so many possibilities. In order of importance:

- Drivers are not installed for your device.
- Even if the drivers are not installed, your USB port may not supply enough power to the device. Try changing port.
- Even if the drivers are installed your USB Cable may be buggy. Try changing it.
- Your ADB process may be not synced. Try with the following commands. `abd kill-server` and then `adb start-server`.
- You may be running more than one adb processes.
- Try restarting Android Studio / Eclipse / ...
- Try restarting your computer.
- Try cleaning the computer allowed to use your device from Settings and re-connect again your device.
- Did you enable the developer mode and enable depuration?
- Throw your computer, with USB cable and USB device through the window. Just kidding lol.